# Navigation border and background not working for a template?

Tags: css

My following code is not working.Means border and background color is not working

```
#navigation ul 
{
background-color: #85A157;
border:3px solid white;
}
```

here is my fiddle http://tinkerbin.com/ooJNXsdD 
i want like this

[image]

please help in correcting my fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

try setting a height on the element like so:

```
#navigation ul 
{
    background-color: #85A157;
    border:3px solid white;
    height: 20px;/*added height*/
}
```

i hope this helps. i added the change to tinkerbin, not sure if it took :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow: hidden` on your `<ul>`, like this : http://tinkerbin.com/AMBfS3MY

Answer (score 1):

After testing this on your Tinkerbin, this worked for me. You need a clearfix. In your CSS:

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<ul>
    ...
    <li class="clear"></li>
</ul>
```

And if you want the navigation bar to flush against the top image, add the following margin-top in your CSS:

```
#navigation ul 
{
    margin-top: 0;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, good point. It's not that you "can't" use it, just semantically incorrect. Changed to <li>, then.

Answer (score 1):

I have just updated your fiddle, I hope you can see where your problems where.
http://tinkerbin.com/g63CbYYZ

For example:

- ul has usually a margin. So you need to reset it.
- Better define styles on div not on ul.
- And a lot more...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
#navigation ul 
{
 background-color: #85A157;
 border:3px solid white;
 margin:0px;
 height:22px;
}

#navigation ul li 
{
 list-style:none;
 float:left;
}

#navigation ul li a
{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none;
 margin:0px 37px 0px 0px;
}
```